# Which verb to use when there are two compound subjects where one subject is possessive noun?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Sarah and Ann’s sister *is/are* away on an important assignment.

Comment: The sentence is ambiguous. Is one person (who is sister of both Sarah and Ann) away, or are two people (one named Sarah and the other only known as Ann's sister) away?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

**Sarah and Ann’s sister are away on an important assignment.**

There are two subject in this sentence: **"Sarah"** and **"Ann’s sister"**. So you should use **"are"**.

If the sentence was:

> Sarah's and Ann’s sister *is/are* away on an important assignment.

with one subject **"Sarah's and Ann’s sister"**, the answer would be **"is"**.

Answer (score 0):

It depends as mentioned in the comment if 2 people are away or if 1 is away.

If only Sarah is away:

> **Sarah, Ann’s sister, is** away on an important assignment.

If both Sarah and Ann’s sister are away:

> **Both Sarah and Ann’s sister** **are** away on an important assignment.

Comment: I think this has been downvoted since you seem to have misunderstood the intention of the sentence.  It's either *Sarah, and Ann's sister* or *the sister of both Sarah and Ann*